# socket.io 404 error: socket.io/?transport=polling&t=OUFK089

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, engine.io

I have recently heard of socket.io, so I wanted to try it out on the hosting service I have at hand after a successful attempt using localhost, but instead of it working, now it just displays this error in the client console: `https://example.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&t=OUFK089`, and I have just been struggling here for the last few days, I have been searching the internet for a answer to my problem, and everywhere I see people who manage to fix it but me not being able to. Here is the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
  io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("User connected: " + socket.id);
  });
});
```

And here is the client html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Zesty testy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.6.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="./client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

..client.js:

```
var socket = io("https://example.com/");
```

And I have been mindlessly changing the code here and there trying to get it to work. And I come here once again trying to get a more insight answer. I think I should mention that where I'm running the server js file from is `https://example.com/foobar/index.js`.

I am expecting it to return 200 and display in the server console that a user has connected with their ID.

Comment: " I think I should mention that where I'm running the server js file from is https://example.com/foobar/index.js." — **How** are you running it? (The impression I get is that you missed a fundamental fact about Node.js applications (which is that you need to run them using Node.js)).

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I was on the terminal for the hosting service I was using and used cd command to get to example.com/foobar and then run "node index.js".

Comment: The way to run nodejs code on hosting server depends on the hosting service. Running the JS on terminal is usually not the right way to do it. Please consult with your hosting platform on how to host your nodejs code (of if they support it at all).